# Corporate identity in Visual studio 2013 (style guide) or blend using C# XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, blend

I want to know if I can apply a corporate identity (style guide) on my application using visual studio 2013 or Blend ? Or I must modify manually all style into my application.

I'm coding in C# and XAML (WPF).

I want apply a new style to the buttons, font, colors ...

Comment: Yes, you can. You could edit existing defaults or use your own resource dictionaries. There's multiple [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx) on this subject available around the web in both the docs and elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for answer me. I will read this article and I return you an answer to say you if I have found that I'm searching :)

Comment: No worries, we'll get you sorted one way or another :)